# Formula for the maximum possible number of 3-cliques (triangles) in an undirected graph

Tags: graph-algorithm

As the question states. I seem to be unable to figure out the formula that corresponds to the paper & pencil results. I am looking for a formula to give me the maximum possible number of triangles in an UNDIRECTED graph.

A triangles is defined as any connection of nodes of path length 3 that forms a cycle. e.g If I have a graph with 1<->2<->3<->1 is a triangle(<-> is an undirected connection). If what a triangle is is unclear the top of page 2 has a figure showing what a triangle is in this context http://arxiv.org/pdf/1202.5230v1.pdf.

Thanks

Comment: [Complete graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph) has all possible combinations of 3 nodes as a triangle. Do you have other requirements on a graph? E.g. planarity?

Comment: No other requirements. @Vesper is correct. Thanks to you both!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C(3,n) should do. Basically, you need a number of combinations of 3 out of your entire set of graph nodes.

EDIT: Since the link is now down as omegamath wants to be monetized, I have to explain further. C(m,n) is a number of possible combinations of M elements out of N different ones, and is equal to `(N!)/(M!*(N-M)!)` where `!` is a factorial operation, that is `N! = 1*2*3*...*N`.

`C(3,n) = (N*(N-1)*(N-2))/(1*2*3)`

Comment: The link you posted is down. Is there any chance you could please detail further your answer? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Matteo Okay, here's some info, you might try searching for combinations and permutations numbers yourself for further detalization.